# How can I make my route component more compact without repeating codes

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react. I have this small challenge. My code currently looks like this.

```js
...
function AppRouter() {
    return (
        <Router>
      <div className="container">
        <Aside />
        <div className="main-content">
          <AppbarMain />
          <div className="main-body">
            <div className="display-body">
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
                    <Route path="/personal" exact component={PersonalInfo} />
                    ...
                    <Route path="/applicant/:id" exact component={UserDetail} />
                    <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
                </Switch>
          </div>
            <div className="footer">
  
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

I however prefer it to look something like this

```js
function AppRouter() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
            <Route path="/personal" exact component={PersonalInfo} />
            ...
            <Route path="/applicant/:id" exact component={UserDetail} />
            <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
            </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

The challenge I have is how I can write a single component/function such that I can pass the components Dashboard, PersonalInfo, UserDetail etc to as props to return a new component so that I won't have to repeat myself in writing the enclosing tags and components for each component like I did in my first snippet.
I hope my explanation is clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a wrapper component and use it in the AppRouter.js:

```
function AppRouter() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <PageWrapper>
             <Switch>
               ....
             </Switch>
          </PageWrapper>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

If you dont want to repeat the Route component over and over you could use a route object array, e.g.:

```
function AppRouter() {
    const routes = [
       { path="/dashboard", component: Dashboard },
       { path="/applicant/:id", component: UserDetail },
       ...
    ];

    return (
        <Router>
          <PageWrapper>
             <Switch>
               {routes.map(route => (
                    <Route id={route.path} path={route.path} exact 
                     component={route.component} />
               )}
             </Switch>
          </PageWrapper>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

In the PageWrapper.js - notice how the children get rendered:

```
function PageWrapper({children}) {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Aside />
        <div className="main-content">
            <AppbarMain />
            <div className="main-body">
              <div className="display-body">
                 {children}
            </div>
            <div className="footer">
              footer
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hi @realAlexBarge, thank you please is it possible you show how one of the Routes in the Switch will look like

Comment: Yo dont want to repeat the Route component?